# Create a pivot comparison table based on site dates

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, lookup

I have a single table called 'sitetotals' in mysql with the structure and data below

```
sitetotals_id | sitetotals_date | sitetotals_site | sitetotals_total  
            1 | 2015-08-08      | siteA           |               50  
            2 | 2015-08-08      | siteB           |               40  
            3 | 2015-08-08      | siteC           |               30  
            4 | 2015-08-08      | siteD           |               20  
            5 | 2015-08-08      | siteE           |               10   
            6 | 2015-08-01      | siteB           |                3  
            7 | 2015-08-01      | siteC           |                2  
            8 | 2015-08-01      | siteD           |                1
```

**Here is what I have so far as a html table**

```
site  | 2015-08-08 | 2015-08-01  
siteA | 50         |  
siteB | 40         |  
siteC | 30         |  
siteD | 20         |  
siteE | 10         |
```

**What I am looking to achieve is the following result**

```
site  | 2015-08-08 | 2015-08-01  
siteA | 50         | 0  
siteB | 40         | 3  
siteC | 30         | 2  
siteD | 20         | 1  
siteE | 10         | 0
```

**Below is my current query**

```
    <h2>GET LATEST DATE AND PREVIOUS DATE</h2>
    <?php
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM sitetotals 
    ORDER BY sitetotals_wc DESC, sitetotals_total DESC
    LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); // Use fetchAll() if you want all results
    $date_raw = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['sitetotals_wc']));
    echo $date_raw." | ".$date_raw7 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('-7 day', strtotime($date_raw)));
    ?>
    <h2>TABLE DATA</h2>
    <?php
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM sitetotals
    ORDER BY sitetotals_wc DESC, sitetotals_total DESC LIMIT 50');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<table class='paginate'><tr><th>Date</th><th>Worst Site</th>
    <th>".$date_raw."</th>
    <th>".$date_raw7."</th>
    </tr>\n";
    foreach($result as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".date_format($date=(date_create($row['sitetotals_wc'])),'d-m-Y')."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['sitetotals_site']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['sitetotals_total']."</td>";
    echo "<td>        HERE IS WHERE THE ANSWER SHOULD GO       </td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
    ?>
```

> if possible I would also like to be able to extend this pivot with
>   multiple report periods

Comment: Can you be certain that all the latest dates and previous dates will be the same?

Comment: @Strawberry dates will be weekly (every monday). so on Monday 1st 50 sites will be added to the table with their totals, then on Monday 8th 50 sites will be added again to the table, so on etc. The 50 sites each week could be the same, totally different or a combo. To explain myself in type as you speak terms I basically need it to do the following.. get the latest (max) date in to table, echo those totals, then look to see if site? was in previous week & echo that total, if not echo 0. Latest week will then move throughout the year & previous week will follow it as a new week is added. Thanks

Comment: But what if a site has no activity in the latest week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### pivoting on dynamic number of dates

#### directly in mysql

**plan**

> - construct dates dimension [ `dim_site_dates_v` ] containing all date periods where there is sitetotals data
> - construct sites dimension [ `dim_sites_v` ] containing all sites with data in sitetotals
> - set number of periods [ `@num_periods` ] to report against
> - join dates and site names over reporting period and write summary values to table [ `sites_summary_tmp` ]
> - use dynamic query template and loop over the reporting space to parameterise query
> - prepare+execute query

**setup**

```
create table sitetotals
(
  sitetotals_id integer primary key not null,
  sitetotals_date date not null,
  sitetotals_site varchar(22) not null,
  sitetotals_total integer not null
);

insert into sitetotals
( sitetotals_id, sitetotals_date, sitetotals_site, sitetotals_total )
values
(1 , '2015-08-08' , 'siteA' , 50 ),  
(2 , '2015-08-08' , 'siteB' , 40 ),
(3 , '2015-08-08' , 'siteC' , 30 ),
(4 , '2015-08-08' , 'siteD' , 20 ),
(5 , '2015-08-08' , 'siteE' , 10 ),
(6 , '2015-08-01' , 'siteB' , 3 ),
(7 , '2015-08-01' , 'siteC' , 2 ),
(8 , '2015-08-01' , 'siteD' , 1 ),
(9 , '2015-08-01' , 'siteF' , 1 ),
(10 , '2015-07-25' , 'siteA' , 22 ),
(11 , '2015-07-25' , 'siteC' , 20 ),
(12 , '2015-07-25' , 'siteD' , 10 ),
(13 , '2015-07-25' , 'siteF' , 5 ),
(14 , '2015-07-18' , 'siteA' , 2 ),
(15 , '2015-07-18' , 'siteC' , 5 ),
(16 , '2015-07-18' , 'siteD' , 3 ),
(17 , '2015-07-18' , 'siteE' , 5 )
;

create view dim_sites_v
as
select distinct sitetotals_site
from sitetotals
;

create view dim_site_dates_v
as
select distinct sitetotals_date
from sitetotals
;

create table sites_summary_tmp
(
  date_nmbr integer not null,
  site_name varchar(22) not null,
  total integer not null,
  primary key ( date_nmbr, site_name )
);

set @num_periods := 4;

-- if you want to reuse this table, truncate/delete previous summary data first..
insert into sites_summary_tmp
( date_nmbr, site_name, total )
select dates.row_num, sites.sitetotals_site, coalesce(sd.sitetotals_total, 0) as total
from dim_sites_v sites
cross join 
(
select sitetotals_date,
@row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_num
from dim_site_dates_v
cross join ( select @row_num := 0 ) as params
order by sitetotals_date desc
) dates
left join sitetotals sd
on sites.sitetotals_site = sd.sitetotals_site
and dates.sitetotals_date = sd.sitetotals_date
where dates.row_num <= @num_periods
;

-- set variables
-- @num_periods should only need to be set once
-- however sqlfiddle uses separate connection for
-- building schema and running sql. so it must be set in this connection
set @num_periods := 4;
set @join_template := ' inner join sites_summary_tmp prev#curr#
on  prev#prev#.site_name = prev#curr#.site_name
and prev#prev#.date_nmbr = prev#curr#.date_nmbr - 1
';
set @field_template := '`#prev#nbr##`,';
set @field_alias_template := 'prev#nbr#.total as `#prev#nbr##`,';
-- pivot report can be generated by joining summary results to itself
-- for each date period. and dynamically aliasing the titles to the 
-- reporting dates.
set @query := 'select site_name,
#select_fields#
from
(
select prev0.site_name, 
#alias_fields#
from sites_summary_tmp prev0
#all_joins#
where prev0.date_nmbr = 1
) pivot
;'
;
```

**query**

```
-- replace parameters in dynamic @query
select count(*)
from
(
select 
@query := replace(@query, '#alias_fields#', 
                  concat(replace(@field_alias_template, '#nbr#', dates.row_num), ' #alias_fields#')),
@query := replace(@query, '#select_fields#', 
                  concat(replace(@field_template, '#nbr#', dates.row_num), ' #select_fields#')),
@query := replace(@query, concat('#prev', dates.row_num, '#'), sitetotals_date),
@query := if(dates.row_num < @num_periods - 1, replace(@query, '#all_joins#', 
                         concat(replace(replace(@join_template, '#prev#', dates.row_num), '#curr#', dates.row_num + 1), 
                         ' #all_joins#')), 
              @query)
from
(
select sitetotals_date,
@row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_num
from dim_site_dates_v
cross join ( select @row_num := -1 ) as params
order by sitetotals_date desc
) dates
where dates.row_num < @num_periods
) suppress_output
into @ignore
;

set @query := replace(replace(replace(@query, '#all_joins#', ''), ', #alias_fields#', ' '), ', #select_fields#', ' ');

PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
deallocate prepare dynamic_statement;
```

**output**

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| site_name | 2015-08-08 | 2015-08-01 | 2015-07-25 | 2015-07-18 |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| siteA     |         50 |          0 |         22 |          2 |
| siteB     |         40 |          3 |          0 |          0 |
| siteC     |         30 |          2 |         20 |          5 |
| siteD     |         20 |          1 |         10 |          3 |
| siteE     |         10 |          0 |          0 |          5 |
| siteF     |          0 |          1 |          5 |          0 |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/430be/36)

---

#### with php

**plan**

> - construct dates dimension [ `dim_site_dates_v` ] containing all date periods where there is sitetotals data
> - construct sites dimension [ `dim_sites_v` ] containing all sites with data in sitetotals
> - set number of periods [ `@num_periods` ] to report against
> - join dates and site names over reporting period and order by date and site return resultset to php
> - php to pivot on date fields

**php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Mysqli initial code
 * 
 * User permissions of database
 * Create, Alter and Index table, Create view, and Select, Insert, Update, Delete table data
 * 
 * @package         PhpFiddle
 * @link            http://phpfiddle.org
 * @since           2012
*/

require "util/public_db_info.php";

$short_connect = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $pass_word, $database_name, $port);

$sql = "set @num_periods := 4";
$result = $short_connect->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($short_connect));

$sql = "select dates.sitetotals_date, sites.sitetotals_site, coalesce(sd.sitetotals_total, 0) as total " .
"from dim_sites_v sites " .
"cross join  " .
"( " .
"select sitetotals_date, " .
"@row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_num " .
"from dim_site_dates_v " .
"cross join ( select @row_num := 0 ) as params " .
"order by sitetotals_date desc " .
") dates " .
"left join sitetotals sd " .
"on sites.sitetotals_site = sd.sitetotals_site " .
"and dates.sitetotals_date = sd.sitetotals_date " .
"where dates.row_num <= @num_periods order by 1 desc,2";
$result = $short_connect->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($short_connect));

$table = array();
$dates = array();
$sites = array();

if (($result) && ($result->num_rows > 0))
{
    $results = array();

    //convert query result into an associative array
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if(!in_array($row["sitetotals_date"], $dates))$dates[] = $row["sitetotals_date"];
        if(!in_array($row["sitetotals_site"], $sites))$sites[] = $row["sitetotals_site"];
        $table[$row["sitetotals_site"]][$row["sitetotals_date"]] = $row["total"];
    }

    $result->free();
}

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>site_name</td>";
foreach($dates as $date)
{
    echo "<td>" . $date . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";

foreach ($sites as $site)
{
    echo "<tr><td>" . $site . "</td>";
    foreach($dates as $date)
    {
        echo "<td>" . $table[$site][$date] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

$short_connect->close();


?>
```

**output**

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>site_name</td>
      <td>2015-08-08</td>
      <td>2015-08-01</td>
      <td>2015-07-25</td>
      <td>2015-07-18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>siteA</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>siteB</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>siteC</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>siteD</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>siteE</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>siteF</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

both solutions can be extended dynamically for number of report periods by adjust value of `@num_periods`. if `@num_periods` is greater than the total number of periods in the data, no rows will be returned..

Comment: Thank you @amdixon that is great, as the sites will be limited to 50 every week and consisting of either the same 50 sites, a totally different 50 sites or combination of (eg 20 from previous week and 30 not in previous week) from a list of 3500+ sites, how would I alter your query to limit to show only 50 results on curr_total and sort curr_total in DESC order. Hope this makes sense, Thanks Rob

Comment: adjusted the query with this new information. changes made : 1. as we only need to report on those that are present in the current period i can remove the query to get allsites and just get this info from those present in curr. 2. add an order by curr_total desc and limit to restrict output report to 50 rows. see updates ( and fiddle ) which specifically does not display siteF as it is not present in current period

Comment: Thanks you @amdixon very much appreciated

Comment: I wonder if you could help me again @amdixon, I am looking to extend this to 4 weeks, would that be possible?

Comment: @blend extended logic to pivot based on dynamic number of periods `@num_periods` in native sql or php+sql